# looking for explanation for a part of a code

Tags: c++

I have this function a student represented by id going to add a course in a specific semester. this code is correct but i don't understand the section when he did
`for (size_t i = 0; i < (*iteratorVectorP).size(); i++) ...`

```
void add_course(map<int, map<int, vector<course *> * > > &DB, int 
     semester, int id, course c)
{
    auto iterator = DB.find(id);    //find id as key, set map to value
    vector<course*> *pointer = new vector<course*>;
    if (iterator != DB.end())
    {
        auto iterator1 = ((*iterator).second).find(semester);   //find                 
        semester as key, set vector to value
        if (iterator1 == (*iterator).second.end())      //if semester does not exist
        {
            pointer->push_back(new course(c));
            (iterator->second)[semester] = pointer;
        }
        else        //if semester exist
        {
            auto iteratorVectorP = (iterator->second)[semester];
            // i do not understand what his doing here 
            for (size_t i = 0; i < (*iteratorVectorP).size(); i++)
            {
                if (c == *(*iteratorVectorP)[i])
                {
                    return;     //exit when class exist
                }
                else
                {
                    (*iteratorVectorP).push_back(new course(c));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What an inconsistent mix of `(*ptr).` and `ptr->`.

Comment: Far too many pointers. Use a `map<int, map<int, vector<course>>>`.

Answer (score 0):

the defination of iteratorVectorP is vector, so the for loop is iterating the course and try to add it in the vector if non-existed.

Comment: if i replace the  vector with a list what changing i could apply  in this (c == *(*iteratorVectorP)[i] because i can not use []?

Comment: change this "for (size_t i = 0; i < (*iteratorVectorP).size(); i++)" to "for (auto it = iteratorVectorP->begin(); i != iteratorVectorP->end(); it++)", or "for (auto const& it: *itratorVectorP)" if you have c++11

Comment: and  this (c == *(*iteratorVectorP)[i])  become like that if (c == it.find(c)) ?

Comment: so how should i do it ?

Comment: c == *it, may by you should compare the course id instead, c.courseId == it->courseId

Answer (score 0):

It looks like iteratorVectorP is a pointer, so calling (*iteratorVectorP).size() will get the value it is pointing to.

Comment: okay, if I replace the vector with a list of courses  what changing I could apply in this (c == *(*iteratorVectorP)[i] because I can not use []